# How do you draw a dative bond with chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How do you draw a dative / coordinate bond with chemfig? I would like to have the bond to appear as an arrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the TikZ parameter of the corresponding bond, i.e., the *fifth* parameter in the optional argument and specify an arrow according to TikZ syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{A-[,,,,->]B-[:30,,,,<-]A}

\end{document}
```

[image]