# How to draw a dative bond between two distant atoms with the `?` hook?

Tags: arrows, chemfig

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3.17cm,right=3.17cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}% normal page sutep
\usepackage[rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%نوع الاسهم للتحكم بها
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\disablefixedbondlength%لعدم ضبط المسافات بين الذرات بصورة الية
\enablefixedbondlength%لاعادة ضبط طول الاواصر بصورة الية
\chemfig[][scale=2]{[:330]{\color{red}N}*6(-*6(=(-{\color{red}HO})-=-([:350]-{\color{red}N}([:300]={\color{red}N}?[a](-[:235]*6(=-=-=([:360]-C([:55]-{\color{blue}O}([:90]-{\color{YellowOrange}Zn}?[a,{>:},blue]?[b]([:90]-{\color{blue}O}([:65]-C([:140]={\color{blue}O})([8]-*6(=([:240]-{\color{red}N}?[b,{<:},green]([:300]={\color{red}N}(-[:5]*6(=(*6(-=-={\color{red}N}--))-=(-{\color{red}OH})-=-))))-=-=-))))))([:310]={\color{blue}O}))-))))=-)--=-=)}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I change the type of bond `{<:}` in my chemfig to the `{\rightarrow}` (a dative bond)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please shorten the title and add the real question to your post

Comment: I want t change bond {>:} to another type \rightarrow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you draw a dative bond with chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280708/how-do-you-draw-a-dative-bond-with-chemfig)

Comment: @Troy Because Zn and N are distant atoms, the OP used the ? hook to create a bond between those atoms. However, the syntax for customization of this bond is different to customization of bonds between adjacent atoms. While clemens answer is certainly relevant, it is a solution for adjacent atoms and won't work for distant atoms. Does N coordinate to Zn (->) or vice versa (<-)?

Comment: @ali I have added an example output, and (hopefully) stated your question clearly. Feel free to revert if I have butchered the original meaning.

Answer (score 2):

This molecule uses the hook "?", explained in section 9 of the `Chemfig` manual, to connect distant atoms. The syntax for customization of the bond set between atoms that have the hook applied is `?[<name>,<bond>,<tikz>]`.

Here, I applied a bond customization with `[a,,{line width=2pt},{<-},{blue}]`, where a is the name of the hook, the empty key is a provision for the type of bond (which can be any of the 9 types of bonds described in section 2 of the `Chemfig` manual), while the follow are `TikZ` keys giving the line width, arrow type, and color.  Applying this to the OP's question gives the following molecule. Note: the direction of the arrow could be incorrect, each TikZ key must be surrounded by braces `{}`, and the line width is just applied for emphasis of the result.

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3.17cm,right=3.17cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}% normal page sutep
\usepackage[rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%نوع الاسهم للتحكم بها
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \disablefixedbondlength%لعدم ضبط المسافات بين الذرات بصورة الية
    \enablefixedbondlength%لاعادة ضبط طول الاواصر بصورة الية
    \chemfig[][scale=1]{[:330]{\color{red}N}*6(-*6(=(-{\color{red}HO})-=-([:350]-{\color{red}N}([:300]={\color{red}N}?[a](-[:235]*6(=-=-=([:360]-C([:55]-{\color{blue}O}([:90]-{\color{YellowOrange}Zn}?[a,,{line width=2pt},{<-},{blue}]?[b]([:90]-{\color{blue}O}([:65]-C([:140]={\color{blue}O})([8]-*6(=([:240]-{\color{red}N}?[b,,{line width=2pt},{->},{green}]([:300]={\color{red}N}(-[:5]*6(=(*6(-=-={\color{red}N}--))-=(-{\color{red}OH})-=-))))-=-=-))))))([:310]={\color{blue}O}))-))))=-)--=-=)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for you, this solution was very useful to this question